# Gravity Form Zoho CRM add-on not working for checkbox fields

Tags: wordpress, crm, gravity-forms-plugin, zoho

Admittedly this might be a little light for this site, but I've been trying to figure this out for 5 hours now and can't find any thing about this on the web...

I've got a Wordpress Gravity Form - with a Zoho CRM feed - and I can't get the checkbox fields to populate in Zoho CRM. When the checkboxes are checked and the form is submitted, The CRM Lead record gets created, all other field types come over correctly (Custom text, multi-select, select), but the checkboxes do not show up as checked in Zoho CRM.  Here is an image of the mapping for a TEST checkbox.  I've tried using both the TEST(Selected) and TEST and neither one works...
[Screen shot of checkbox field mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cnvL.png)

Does anyone out there have any experience working with this? I would really appreciate any help - thanks!!

Comment: Gravity Forms provides support https://www.gravityhelp.com/support/

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm setting this up for a client and don't currently have access to the original license info which is what you need to request support - working that angle too!

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too, but have found the solution:

1. You need to "show values" in Gravity Form for the checkbox field and
   add in the value "True" instead of the label name for the checkbox
   field that might be there. (see screenshot)

   2. When mapping to Zoho, choose the label field for that checkbox from the drop down, not the Checkbox Name(Selected) field. (see screenshot)

**showing true value entered**
[image]

**showing label value selected in Zoho Mapping**
[image]